# String formatted using String.Format not displaying in Print Preview

Tags: vb.net, string, format, drawstring

I'm trying to create a print function with a corresponding print preview. For some reason, any string I create with String.Format will NOT show up on the print preview!  Use the code snippet below as an example:

```
Dim strTemp As String
strTemp = String.Format("{0, 210} {1, 75} {2, 51} {3, 200} ",
                        "NAME", "PRICE", "QUANTITY", "DESCRIPTION")
e.Graphics.DrawString("hi" + strTemp,
                      New Font("Courier New", 9, FontStyle.Bold),
                      Brushes.Black, 150, 10)
```

In this example, "hi" will display in the print preview, but strTemp will not. I've tried many things - using ToString even though it's already a string, putting the String.Format() call directly inside of DrawString(), just to name a few.  Can anybody shed light on why this isn't working?

Comment: Perhaps the text is written _beyond_ the image bounds. Did you check for that?

Comment: Gosh, the number of spaces was the problem. Not only did I not know that spacing takes place before each value, I also didn't realize how big the spacing actually is. I feel silly. Thanks for the help - and thanks for the edit, by the way. I'll be sure to use that from now on. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have lots of spaces there - chances are that the text is written outside the image bounds and therefore not showing up.